# How send whatsapp images on sketchware? not shared

Tags: html

If we want to send whatsapp message then we use : "whatsapp://send?text="
But how about sending image?
What should i do to send image? Not share image.

[image: this is for send text]

Comment: Are you using an API? What technologies are you using?

Comment: Have you checked out the [WhatsApp API - Media Messages documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/media)?